# Theme parks about Japan outside of Japan

Tags: japan, amusement-parks

What theme parks in countries other than Japan are there about Japan?

They should be in countries that are accessible to Japanese people, so easy visa access to Japanese citizens, and support for Japanese or English-speaking tourists would be a positive.

Ideally they should be mainly about Japan, rather than a theme park about a large number of countries which just happen to include Japan.

I tried googling, but mainly got hits about [theme parks in Japan about other countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9305/324).

Comment: @gulliver too broad.

Comment: Does the Japanese pavilion at Disney's Epcot Center count?

Comment: @Itai it's a possibility, though it being part of a larger thing with several countries makes it less special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Japanese Friendship Garden in San Jose, California (SJC), which should be easily accessible from Japan.  The park is relatively close to the downtown area (where the SJC airport is located), and generally has free admission for most gardens (although some other events around it sometime require a separate admission).